# Error while compiling HAProxy from source

Tags: lua, centos7, haproxy, arm64

I got this error while trying to compile the HAProxy 2.2 with LUA version 5.3. I'm on trying to do it on CentOS7(arm64).

```
[root@08d17a479616 haproxy-2.2.22]# make TARGET=linux-glibc USE_PCRE=1 USE_PCRE_JIT=1 USE_OPENSSL=1 USE_ZLIB=1 USE_LINUX_TPROXY=1 USE_REGPARM=1 USE_LUA=1 USE_THREAD=1 USE_TFO=1
  CC      src/version.o
  LD      haproxy
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -latomic
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

More logs;

```
attempt to open //usr/aarch64-redhat-linux/lib64/libatomic.so failed
attempt to open //usr/aarch64-redhat-linux/lib64/libatomic.a failed
attempt to open //usr/lib64/libatomic.so failed
attempt to open //usr/lib64/libatomic.a failed
attempt to open //usr/local/lib64/libatomic.so failed
attempt to open //usr/local/lib64/libatomic.a failed
attempt to open //lib64/libatomic.so failed
attempt to open //lib64/libatomic.a failed
attempt to open //usr/aarch64-redhat-linux/lib/libatomic.so failed
attempt to open //usr/aarch64-redhat-linux/lib/libatomic.a failed
attempt to open //usr/local/lib/libatomic.so failed
attempt to open //usr/local/lib/libatomic.a failed
attempt to open //lib/libatomic.so failed
attempt to open //lib/libatomic.a failed
attempt to open //usr/lib/libatomic.so failed
attempt to open //usr/lib/libatomic.a failed
ld: cannot find -latomic
[root@08d17a479616 haproxy-2.2.22]#
```

What I've tried until now is to create a symlink to the libatomic.so with this

```
ln -s /usr/lib64/libatomic.so.1.2.0 /usr/lib/libatomic.so
```

And installed the missing GNU library from [here](https://centos.pkgs.org/7/centos-sclo-rh-aarch64/devtoolset-7-libatomic-devel-7.3.1-5.16.el7.aarch64.rpm.html) with the steps outline in the article.

```
Install CentOS SCLo RH repository:yum install centos-release-scl-rh
Install devtoolset-7-libatomic-devel rpm package:
# yum install devtoolset-7-libatomic-devel
```

What should I do to resolve it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by installing this package and it goes through to a new error, which I've outlitned in this question.
New question: [New questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74303918/lua-issue-while-compiling-haproxy)

To apply the fix for CentOS7 arm, use this link and the instructions on how to install the package.
[Package Link](https://centos.pkgs.org/7/centos-aarch64/systemd-devel-219-78.el7.aarch64.rpm.html)

```
Install systemd-devel rpm package:  yum install systemd-devel
```