# Lua issue while compiling it with HAProxy

Tags: lua, arm, centos7, haproxy, arm64

Here is the issue..
When I run the command make -j $(nproc) TARGET=linux-glibc USE_PCRE=1 USE_PCRE_JIT=1 USE_OPENSSL=1 USE_ZLIB=1 USE_LINUX_TPROXY=1 USE_REGPARM=1 USE_LUA=1 USE_THREAD=1 USE_TFO=1

I get the error below.. I'm trying to build HaProxy 2.5 with Lua 5.4 from source.

```
  src/hlua.o: In function `hlua_yieldk':
/src/haproxy-2.5.5/src/hlua.c:1158: undefined reference to `lua_yieldk'
src/hlua.o: In function `hlua_hook':
/src/haproxy-2.5.5/src/hlua.c:1325: undefined reference to `lua_isyieldable'
src/hlua.o: In function `hlua_yieldk':
/src/haproxy-2.5.5/src/hlua.c:1158: undefined reference to `lua_yieldk'
src/hlua.o: In function `hlua_load_state':
/src/haproxy-2.5.5/src/hlua.c:11134: undefined reference to `luaL_loadfilex'
/src/haproxy-2.5.5/src/hlua.c:11142: undefined reference to `lua_pcallk'
src/hlua.o: In function `hlua_prepend_path':
/src/haproxy-2.5.5/src/hlua.c:11236: undefined reference to `lua_getglobal'
src/hlua.o: In function `hlua_filter_parse_fct':
/src/haproxy-2.5.5/src/hlua.c:10875: undefined reference to `lua_tointegerx'
src/hlua.o: In function `hlua_sleep_yield':
/src/haproxy-2.5.5/src/hlua.c:8289: undefined reference to `lua_tointegerx'
src/hlua.o: In function `hlua_yieldk':
/src/haproxy-2.5.5/src/hlua.c:1158: undefined reference to `lua_yieldk'
/src/haproxy-2.5.5/src/hlua.c:1158: undefined reference to `lua_yieldk'
/src/haproxy-2.5.5/src/hlua.c:1158: undefined reference to `lua_yieldk'
src/hlua.o: In function `hlua_applet_tcp_recv_yield':
/src/haproxy-2.5.5/src/hlua.c:4557: undefined reference to `lua_copy'
src/hlua.o: In function `hlua_yieldk':
/src/haproxy-2.5.5/src/hlua.c:1158: undefined reference to `lua_yieldk'
/src/haproxy-2.5.5/src/hlua.c:1158: undefined reference to `lua_yieldk'
src/hlua.o: In function `hlua_txn_reply_add_header':
/src/haproxy-2.5.5/src/hlua.c:8185: undefined reference to `lua_rawlen'
src/hlua.o: In function `hlua_applet_http_addheader':
/src/haproxy-2.5.5/src/hlua.c:5242: undefined reference to `lua_rawlen'
src/hlua.o: In function `hlua_txn_reply_new':
/src/haproxy-2.5.5/src/hlua.c:8067: undefined reference to `lua_rotate'
/src/haproxy-2.5.5/src/hlua.c:8071: undefined reference to `lua_rotate'
/src/haproxy-2.5.5/src/hlua.c:8088: undefined reference to `lua_rawlen'
/src/haproxy-2.5.5/src/hlua.c:8007: undefined reference to `lua_tointegerx'
src/hlua.o: In function `hlua_filter_init_per_thread':
/src/haproxy-2.5.5/src/hlua.c:10299: undefined reference to `lua_rotate'
/src/haproxy-2.5.5/src/hlua.c:10319: undefined reference to `lua_rawlen'
/src/haproxy-2.5.5/src/hlua.c:10322: undefined reference to `lua_pcallk'
src/hlua.o: In function `hlua_lua2arg':
/src/haproxy-2.5.5/src/hlua.c:603: undefined reference to `lua_tointegerx'
src/hlua.o: In function `hlua_lua2smp':
/src/haproxy-2.5.5/src/hlua.c:739: undefined reference to `lua_tointegerx'
src/hlua.o: In function `hlua_yieldk':
/src/haproxy-2.5.5/src/hlua.c:1158: undefined reference to `lua_yieldk'
src/hlua.o: In function `hlua_txn_forward_reply':
/src/haproxy-2.5.5/src/hlua.c:7757: undefined reference to `lua_tointegerx'
src/hlua.o: In function `hlua_yieldk':
/src/haproxy-2.5.5/src/hlua.c:1158: undefined reference to `lua_yieldk'
/src/haproxy-2.5.5/src/hlua.c:1158: undefined reference to `lua_yieldk'
/src/haproxy-2.5.5/src/hlua.c:1158: undefined reference to `lua_yieldk'
/src/haproxy-2.5.5/src/hlua.c:1158: undefined reference to `lua_yieldk'
/src/haproxy-2.5.5/src/hlua.c:1158: undefined reference to `lua_yieldk'
src/hlua.o:/src/haproxy-2.5.5/src/hlua.c:1158: more undefined references to `lua_yieldk' follow
src/hlua.o: In function `hlua_http_get_headers':
/src/haproxy-2.5.5/src/hlua.c:5614: undefined reference to `lua_rawlen'
src/hlua.o: In function `hlua_yieldk':
/src/haproxy-2.5.5/src/hlua.c:1158: undefined reference to `lua_yieldk'
src/hlua.o: In function `hlua_socket_connect':
/src/haproxy-2.5.5/src/hlua.c:2742: undefined reference to `luaL_prepbuffsize'
src/hlua.o: In function `hlua_yieldk':
/src/haproxy-2.5.5/src/hlua.c:1158: undefined reference to `lua_yieldk'
src/hlua.o: In function `hlua_httpclient_get_headers':
/src/haproxy-2.5.5/src/hlua.c:7022: undefined reference to `lua_rawlen'
src/hlua.o: In function `hlua_applet_http_recv_yield':
/src/haproxy-2.5.5/src/hlua.c:5094: undefined reference to `lua_copy'
src/hlua.o: In function `hlua_yieldk':
/src/haproxy-2.5.5/src/hlua.c:1158: undefined reference to `lua_yieldk'
/src/haproxy-2.5.5/src/hlua.c:1158: undefined reference to `lua_yieldk'
/src/haproxy-2.5.5/src/hlua.c:1158: undefined reference to `lua_yieldk'
/src/haproxy-2.5.5/src/hlua.c:1158: undefined reference to `lua_yieldk'
/src/haproxy-2.5.5/src/hlua.c:1158: undefined reference to `lua_yieldk'
src/hlua.o:/src/haproxy-2.5.5/src/hlua.c:1158: more undefined references to `lua_yieldk' follow
src/hlua.o: In function `hlua_applet_http_send_response':
/src/haproxy-2.5.5/src/hlua.c:5345: undefined reference to `lua_tointegerx'
src/hlua.o: In function `hlua_yieldk':
/src/haproxy-2.5.5/src/hlua.c:1158: undefined reference to `lua_yieldk'
src/hlua.o: In function `hlua_socket_receive_yield':
/src/haproxy-2.5.5/src/hlua.c:2069: undefined reference to `lua_tointegerx'
src/hlua.o: In function `hlua_yieldk':
/src/haproxy-2.5.5/src/hlua.c:1158: undefined reference to `lua_yieldk'
src/hlua.o: In function `hlua_socket_receive':
/src/haproxy-2.5.5/src/hlua.c:2279: undefined reference to `lua_copy'
/src/haproxy-2.5.5/src/hlua.c:2268: undefined reference to `lua_tointegerx'
src/hlua.o: In function `hlua_yieldk':
/src/haproxy-2.5.5/src/hlua.c:1158: undefined reference to `lua_yieldk'
src/hlua.o: In function `hlua_filter_callback':
/src/haproxy-2.5.5/src/hlua.c:10615: undefined reference to `lua_rotate'
/src/haproxy-2.5.5/src/hlua.c:10658: undefined reference to `lua_rotate'
/src/haproxy-2.5.5/src/hlua.c:10673: undefined reference to `lua_tointegerx'
src/hlua.o: In function `hlua_filter_tcp_payload':
/src/haproxy-2.5.5/src/hlua.c:10812: undefined reference to `lua_tointegerx'
src/hlua.o: In function `hlua_filter_http_payload':
/src/haproxy-2.5.5/src/hlua.c:10776: undefined reference to `lua_tointegerx'
src/hlua.o: In function `hlua_yieldk':
/src/haproxy-2.5.5/src/hlua.c:1158: undefined reference to `lua_yieldk'
src/hlua.o: In function `hlua_action':
/src/haproxy-2.5.5/src/hlua.c:9076: undefined reference to `lua_tointegerx'
src/hlua.o: In function `hlua_filter_new':
/src/haproxy-2.5.5/src/hlua.c:10487: undefined reference to `lua_rotate'
src/hlua.o: In function `hlua_yieldk':
/src/haproxy-2.5.5/src/hlua.c:1158: undefined reference to `lua_yieldk'
src/hlua.o: In function `hlua_init_state':
/src/haproxy-2.5.5/src/hlua.c:11723: undefined reference to `lua_setglobal'
/src/haproxy-2.5.5/src/hlua.c:11746: undefined reference to `lua_setglobal'
/src/haproxy-2.5.5/src/hlua.c:11768: undefined reference to `lua_setglobal'
/src/haproxy-2.5.5/src/hlua.c:11814: undefined reference to `lua_setglobal'
src/hlua_fcn.o: In function `hlua_stktable_dump':
/src/haproxy-2.5.5/src/hlua_fcn.c:719: undefined reference to `lua_rawlen'
/src/haproxy-2.5.5/src/hlua_fcn.c:744: undefined reference to `lua_tointegerx'
src/hlua_fcn.o: In function `hlua_fcn_post_init':
/src/haproxy-2.5.5/src/hlua_fcn.c:1390: undefined reference to `lua_getglobal'
src/hlua_fcn.o: In function `hlua_fcn_reg_core_fcn':
/src/haproxy-2.5.5/src/hlua_fcn.c:1713: undefined reference to `lua_setglobal'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [haproxy] Error 1
```

When using the default Lua, which is 5.1.4 for CentOS7 then HAProxy can't find it. HaProxy doesn't work with 5.1.4 Lua. After updating the Lua to 5.3 or above and running the command

```
 make -j $(nproc) TARGET=linux-glibc USE_PCRE=1 USE_PCRE_JIT=1 USE_OPENSSL=1 USE_ZLIB=1 USE_LINUX_TPROXY=1 USE_REGPARM=1 USE_LUA=1 LUA_LIB_NAME=lua5.4 USE_THREAD=1 USE_TFO=1
```

I still get the error above. Please have in mind that the CentOS7 is a ARM64 infrastructure. I tried to build the HAProxy and Lua on AMD64 and it went through successfully. Is it possible that this is an ARM issue ?

Comment: It looks like the Lua library isn't being linked at all. Or maybe the library was built for the wrong architecture?

Comment: Good point Siguza! I don't know if there is a Lua release for ARM. I have to look into it. However even if I compile it from source I'm able to see the Lua version being updated to 5.4.  in addition to your answer I may try with describing the path to Lua.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay to fix this issue first install the latest Lua package, then compile the HaProxy by using this command.

```
make -j $(nproc) USE_NS=1 > USE_TFO=1 > USE_ZLIB=1 > USE_LUA=1 > USE_PCRE=1 > USE_SYSTEMD=1 > USE_LIBCRYPT=1 > USE_THREAD=1 > TARGET=linux-glibc > LUA_INC=/src/lua-5.3.3/include > LUA_LIB=/src/lua-5.3.3/lib
```

Just outline the path of the Lua library and include directories.